# How to use javax.inject Provider<T> within spring xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, provider, inject

I have a class called let's say A with such a setter:

```
//class A
@Inject
public void setAProvider(Provider<B> b)
{
    this.b = b;
}
```

It works fine with javax.inject and annotation configuration when I want to have only one kind of A instance..
My problem is that I want to have two instances of class A, one with `Provider<B1>` and second with `Provider<B2>`. My question is how to express my requirements in Spring xml configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is briefly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435117/when-to-use-javax-inject-provider-in-spring), you need `ProviderCreatingFactoryBean` .

This is an example :

```
<bean id="a" class="a.b.b.A" scope="prototype">
    <property name="xxx" value="15000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="a.b.b.B" scope="prototype">
    <property name="zzz" value="-1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="providerOfA" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ProviderCreatingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetBeanName" value="a"/>
</bean>

<bean id="providerOfB" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ProviderCreatingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetBeanName" value="b"/>
</bean>

<bean id="barServiceA" class="a.b.c.BarService">
    <property name="provider" ref="providerOfA"/>
</bean>

<bean id="barServiceB" class="a.b.c.BarService">
    <property name="provider" ref="providerOfB"/>
</bean>
```