# When to use javax.inject.Provider in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, provider

What it does is pretty simple:

```
@Inject
private Provider<ProductService> productService;
```

The Product service is available through `productService.get()` and `.get()` will resolve the instance from the Spring context on each call.

But when should I use it? And where?

My main use case is pretty simple: When I get circular dependencies, the provider helps to resolve the dependency at runtime. But it looks a bit random if you throw it in just when you can't create your context caused by a circular dependency.

Are there any known patterns about the usage of Providers?

Comment: Looks similar to Dagger Provider :  http://square.github.io/dagger/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This interface is equivalent to `org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory<T>` that is typically used to avoid `BeanFactory.getBean()` calls in client code when looking for prototype instances. Often used with `ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean` to get prototypes beans sourced by the `BeanFactory`.

example from `ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean` javadocs:

```
<beans>

   <!-- Prototype bean since we have state -->
   <bean id="myService" class="a.b.c.MyService" scope="prototype"/>

   <bean id="myServiceFactory"
       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean">
     <property name="targetBeanName"><idref local="myService"/></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="clientBean" class="a.b.c.MyClientBean">
     <property name="myServiceFactory" ref="myServiceFactory"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

With `Providers`, you can use the `ProviderCreatingFactoryBean` instead.

Other option to solve the same problem, (using inheritance instead composition) is the 
[lookup method injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection)

Answer (score 44):

In cdi, Providers are used to inject objects of narrower scope into a more broadly-scoped bean, e.g., if a session-scoped bean needs access to a request scoped object it injects a provider and then a method, which is running in a request, calls `provider.get()` to obtain a local variable reference to the appropriate request-scoped object.

Given the following:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Bean1 {
    void doSomething();
}
```

The following will use the Bean1 instance associated with the first request in the session to use Bean2 regardless of which request is calling Bean2.doSomething():

```
@SessionScoped
public class Bean2 {
    @Inject Bean1 bean;

    public void doSomething() {
        bean.doSomething();
    }
}
```

The following will use the instance of Bean associated with the particular request that is currently calling Bean3.doSomething() i.e. a different bean for each request:

```
@SessionScoped
public class Bean3 {
    @Inject Provider<Bean1> bean;

    public void doSomething() {
        bean.get().doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always good if you support your answers by injecting some code in it. That makes it easy to understand.

Comment: Plus it gives you lazy loading of the injected bean.

Comment: Here you injected the provider with `@Inject Provider<Bean1> bean;`, which injects the default provider for the type `Bean1`. What if there are multiple Named beans for class `Bean1`? How do you say the provider to return a particular Named bean?