# Re-Inject Spring Autowired dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I need to reinject a dependency once it is initialized w/o re-initializing of Application Context.

in detail below is what my requirement

if DB is down application should not perform any transaction , once DB is up application should resume.

this is what i am doing

i have created mongoTemplate , autowiring with attr (required=false). so that when application is getting deployed , even though DB is down ,deployment should not fail .

**problem** :::

but when DB will be up is there any way to reinitialize mongoTemplate and inject it again w/o rebooting server or re-deployment of application.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Provider for changing dependencies.
See [When to use javax.inject.Provider in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435117/when-to-use-javax-inject-provider-in-spring) for more information.

Comment: Should probably provide a code example or more guidance than that